# ios app downloaded from testflight is not able to launch

Tags: ios, testflight

One of our QA engineers installed the latest build from testflight. the app is not able to launch. the app icon turns gray after we tapped it, waited for 2 or 3 minutes it becomes the original state. there is no crash log generated because it is not launched.

xcode: 8.3.3
test device: iphone 6 plus with ios 10.3.3

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try it on different devices? Did you restart the device? Did you reinstall it? Does the device work with other builds? Does the build work with other devices? Does the problem occur on any other device? Did you try upload a new build ? I can go on forever. You need to provide more details for this to be even slightly solvable.

Comment: well Sneak, the end user will not try to install on different devices. Most of them have only one. Of course, I have tried all these. it works.

Comment: thank you for your help! Sneak! very inspiring!

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help. I had a similar problem with my phone a few days ago but the apps in question were not downloaded from TestFlight. Some of my apps (including Facebook and Gmail) started depicting this behaviour where the icon will turn grey on launch and stay that way for a while. It took quite a lot of restarts and completely turning the device off and back on again to fix it. Maybe something to do with the iOS version. Don't know for sure